# Loop through files to find a string and send files containing that string to directories of the same name in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, directory, grep, cat

I have a parent directory with ~500 files with each filename beginning with `cert`, i.e. `cert-104.mol2`, `cert-105.mol2` and so on. Each of these `cert` files contains a seven number identifier inside, i.e. `7988114`. There are ~20 unique seven number identifiers. I have created a directory (`unique_ligands`) that contains a directory for each of the unique identifiers, i.e. a directory named `7988114`. Inside each of those directories is a `.mol2` file with the identifier's name, i.e. `7988114.mol2`. To summarize, the file structure looks like this:

```
/parent/unique_ligands/7988114/7988114.mol2
```

where 7988114 is one of ~20 unique identifiers.

In the parent directory with ~500 files, I need to loop through each cert file, pick out the unique seven number identifier, and send it to the corresponding `identifier.mol2` file. As a beginning bash scripter, I am unsure how to approach this. I wrote code that does this process for a single identifier, `7988114`:

```
find . -type f -name 'cert*' -exec grep -q '7988114' {} ';' -exec cp {} ./unique_ligands/7988114 ';'
cd unique_ligands/7988114
bash -c 'cat $(for((i=0;i<10000;i++)); do echo -n "cert-${i}.mol2 "; done) > zzz.txt 2> ./null'
mv zzz.txt 7988114.mol2
rm null
rm cert*
```

How can I turn this into a loop that will be able to pick out any seven number identifier? Or is there some better way of approaching this?

**edit**

To clarify what each line does in my sample code above:

`find ...` This line searches through all of the ~500 files beginning with the filename `cert` and picks out those files whose contents contain the string `7988114` and copies them to the correct `7988114` directory. Each `cert` file contains ~100 lines of molecular coordinates, information about charges, and so on.

`bash -c ...` this line loops through each of the `cert` files copied into the `7988114` directory, and adds the file contents to a new text file, `zzz.txt`. Each of the `cert` files is named something like `cert-1.mol2`, `cert-2.mol2` and so on. Crucially for me, this line searches through each of those `cert` files going from 1 all the way to an upper limit of 10,000 and adds them to `zzz.txt` in that sequential order. Other examples I found either didn't search in a sequential order or went through the `cert-1*` files before going through the `cert-2*` files.

`mv zzz.txt 7988114.mol2` For some reason I wasn't allowed to create a `7988114.mol2` file above, so I made it here

Comment: `while read ligand ; do find /path/to/corrct/place/to/start_looking ...  -cp ... "$ligand" ...; cd unique_ligands/"$ligand" ; bash ... ${ligand} ; mv .. "${ligand}".mol2 ; rm null ; rm cert* ; done < ligand_list_of_20.txt` This will need a little work, so be sure to set up a small test environment. Also, did you really want `2>/dev/null`, then you don't need to `rm null`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the tips - I tried using 2>/dev/null, but consistenly got an error saying that it didn't exist. I checked and it does exist. Half an hour of fruitless searching later, I just went with a work around

Comment: what do you get for `uname -srv` ? Yes, your original `2> ./null ; ... ; rm ./null` was fine given this constraint, but this would be a first! Good luck.

Comment: Here is what I get:
`uname -srv`

`Linux 4.15.0-55-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 2 18:22:20 UTC 2019`

Comment: Nothing about the OS looks accient or proprietary. Can't say why `/dev/null` can take input. Otherwise, do you need more help with the `while` loop? Hope that helped. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I could honestly use some more help with the `while` loop. In the `do` and `bash` lines you commented, I don't think I'm inserting `$ligand` into the right place amongst my code from the question, because I don't get an output. 

From what I've read, I would need a `ligand_list_of_20.txt` to iterate through the ~20 choices for `$ligand`. Is that correct? Thanks for your help!

Comment: so for development purposes, make a `ligand_list_of_2.txt` . AND add a new `**edit**` section to your Q to include what is in `zzzz.txt` when you run it for a small number, i.e. `cat $(for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo -n "cert-${i}.mol2 "; done) > zzz.txt`. What time zone are you in. I'm in the US-Midwest. Good luck.

Comment: Arg, and there is no reason for all of that `bash -c` stuff. Please show me output of `uname -srv` and `echo $BASH_VERSION`. Your script's first line should be `#!/bin/bash`. This tells the OS what program to use to process the rest of the file. Then you can just have `for((i=0;i<10;i++)); do echo -n "cert-${i}.mol2 "; done> zzz.txt` . Good luck.

Comment: Using your `while` loops and comments as a guide, I actually figured out how to do this. Thanks for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way I figured out how to answer my own question above (with help and inspiration from user shellter above - thanks!):

```
ls -l | grep ^d | awk '{print $9}' > list_of_ligands.txt
mv list_of_ligands.txt ..

cd ..

while read NAME
do
        echo "$NAME"
        grep -l "$NAME" cert* | while read -r filename ; do
        cp $filename unique_ligands/$NAME
        cd unique_ligands/$NAME
        bash -c 'cat $(for((i=0;i<10000;i++)); do echo -n "cert-${i}.mol2 "; done) > zzz.txt 2> ./null'
        mv zzz.txt $NAME.mol2
        rm null
        rm cert*
        cd ../..
done
done < list_of_ligands.txt
```

As I mentioned in my initial question, I had previously created a directory for each 7 number identifier. The `ls -l` line picks out the directory name and creates a vertical list of the directory names (which, again, is simply each 7 number identifier I have).

The two `while` loops iterate through each 7 number identifier I have, and perform the commands I mentioned in my initial question.

Comment: glad you figured it out! Good show! (but please note my comment about your line of code begining with `bash -c` above, you're wasting cycles using `bash -c` (not that it probably affects your run-time too much), but it's not good to get into inefficient habits, when you really need something to zip, you'll only get piz ;-) . Keep posting and good luck.